# Scrapinghub exporting multiple items

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapinghub

In [scrapinghub](https://scrapinghub.com/) how can we achieve multiple items exporting?

I have `MainItem()` and a `SubItem()` item classes and I would like to get two separate items in scrapinghub item's page.

> I can do this by implementing different `item pipelines` for both
>   items in a normal crawling but how this can be achieved in
>   scrapinghub? As of now, I'm getting only `MainItem()` objects in
>   `items page`.

sample code snippet given below,

```
def parse_data(self, response):
    .
    .
    .
    # main item fields
    m_item = MainItem()
    m_item['a'] = 'A'
    m_item['b'] = 'B'
    yield m_item

    # sub item fields
    s_item = SubItem()
    s_item['c'] = 'C'
    s_item['d'] = 'D'
    yield s_item
```

Here in `scrapinghub` I'm able to view only `MainItems()` fields

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more information? The spider code and logs, I can't see any problem with your example.

Scrapy Cloud does allow a spider to yield different items. These items can be filtered later using the SC interface.